# How to fix Checkbox bug?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Whenever I try to click the checkbox on the page it doesn't check the actual box. I know this is something wrong in my ReactJS but I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can you possibly help?

I have tried researching answers on stack and other websites but have turned up with nothing.

```
class Description extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: false,
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Checking Account"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Checking Account &nbsp;
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Savings Account"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Savings Account &nbsp;
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="CDs/Money Market Accounts"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        CDs/Money Market Accounts &nbsp;
                </label>
                <br />
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Student Banking"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Student Banking &nbsp;
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Auto Loans"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Auto Loans &nbsp;
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Home Equity"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Home Equity &nbsp;
                </label>
                <br />
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Mortgage"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Mortgage &nbsp;
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Student Loans"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Student Loans &nbsp;
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Saving for Retirement"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Saving for Retirement &nbsp;
                </label>
                <br />
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Investment Account"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Investment Account &nbsp;
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Credit Card"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Credit Card &nbsp;
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input
                        name="Other"
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={this.state.checked}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                        Other &nbsp;
                </label>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Description/>,
    document.getElementById('checkbox')
);
```

I would like for the program to be able to check the box by the end of this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example for Student Banking

Change name Student Banking to studentBanking
Change this.state.checked to this.state.studentBanking

Change

```
   <input
                    name="Student Banking"
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.state.checked}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

To

```
    <input
                    name="studentBanking"
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={this.state.studentBanking}
                    onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

Do the same for other input checkboxes as well

Comment: This worked perfectly I don't understand why but I appreciate the answer was very helpful!!

Comment: You are welcome. That’s because you are doing setState for selected checkbox dynamically using event.target.name so name has to be studentBanking but not Student Banking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `checked` state value using `setState` in your `onChange` event.

```
 handleInputChange(event) {
            const target = event.target;
            const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
            const name = target.name;

            this.setState({
                checked: value
            });
        }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly I don't understand why but I appreciate the answer was very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the **State** correctly but the check isn't working because of the way the **checked** is bound.

please change

```
checked={this.state.checked}
```

to

```
checked={this.state.StudentBanking}
```

also, remove the **space** in your names

```
<input
   name="CheckingAccount"
   type="checkbox"
   checked={this.state.CheckingAccount}
   onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

Comment: This worked perfectly I don't understand why but I appreciate the answer was very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are setting state as  `{ "Credit Card": true }` when clicking on Credit Card. What you can do is just set the values accordingly.
I have a simple [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6yzy060jzk) using your code itself.